# Webstarts downloads classes directly from server in 1.8.0u9x?

Tags: java, java-8, java-web-start

I've just updated my java version to 1.8.0u92 and now my little java webstart application (fully signed from https) starts up really slowly (over 4 minutes).

I enabled tracing in my webstart and see that webstart tries to download every single class file from my server:

```
security: Istrusted: http://example.com/deploy/w/w.jnlp true
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@111b04e: 3
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@111b04e: 4
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/Category.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/Category.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://example.com:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/Category.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/Category.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://example.com:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/spi/AppenderAttachable.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/spi/AppenderAttachable.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://example.com:80 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/spi/AppenderAttachable.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://example.com/deploy/w/org/apache/log4j/spi/AppenderAttachable.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://example.com:80 with proxy=DIRECT
```

...

A simple test case I created works fine, webstart only downloads the jar and starts up fine and fast.

When i downgrade to 1.8.0u77 everything works again.

I of course cleaned all caches.

This problem seems to be related to something that changed in 1.8.0u91 or 1.8.0u92. I looked through the bug fixes but couldn't find much.

Anyone got a bright idea?

Update
I've added a jar dependency to my test case

```
<jar href="mainapp_lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" />
```

and now my webstart starts to download every single class file from that dependency from the server. Which results in many 404's at serverside, cause only the jar is available.